# Interface goes missing from ifconfig in DPDK

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, ifconfig, dpdk

I am running Oracle VirtualBox and i have created two interfaces. I run DPDK and i add one interface to DPDK and i see that it goes missing from my ifconfig.

Screen shots below:

```
root@VirtualBox:/home/akabra/dpdk/dpdk-2.0.0/tools# ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:3f:34:56  
      inet addr:192.168.0.123  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3f:3456/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:20982 (20.9 KB)  TX bytes:3724 (3.7 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f7:13:f5  
      inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef7:13f5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:51932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:660805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:32407739 (32.4 MB)  TX bytes:1647410289 (1.6 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:358901 (358.9 KB)  TX bytes:358901 (358.9 KB)

root@VirtualBox:/home/akabra/dpdk/dpdk-2.0.0/tools# ./dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
```

## Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver

## Network devices using kernel driver

```
 0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' if=eth1 drv=e1000 unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
 0000:00:08.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' if=eth2 drv=e1000 unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
```

## Other network devices

```
root@VirtualBox:/home/akabra/dpdk/dpdk-2.0.0/tools# ./dpdk_nic_bind.py -b igb_uio 0000:00:08.0

root@VirtualBox:/home/akabra/dpdk/dpdk-2.0.0/tools# ./dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
```

## Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver

```
0000:00:08.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci
```

## Network devices using kernel driver

```
0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' if=eth1 drv=e1000 unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
```

## Other network devices

I dont see my eth2 that i had added I modified to use a DPDK compatible driver.

```
 root@VirtualBox:/home/akabra/dpdk/dpdk-2.0.0/tools# ifconfig
 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:3f:34:56  
      inet addr:192.168.0.123  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3f:3456/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:27757 (27.7 KB)  TX bytes:12789 (12.7 KB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:360948 (360.9 KB)  TX bytes:360948 (360.9 KB)
```

Comment: DPDK's igb_uio driver does not generate 'netdev' interfaces, so I cannot see any interface via ifconfig. (However, they are registered as 'rte_eth_dev' in the DPDK application.)

I should use KNI drivers to have 'netdev' interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK's igb_uio driver does not generate 'netdev' interfaces, so I cannot see any interface via ifconfig. (However, they are registered as 'rte_eth_dev' in the DPDK application.) I should use KNI drivers to have 'netdev' interfaces